# 4000W Dimmer Eagle PCB Design

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, dimmer

I am trying to learn how to design PCBs, and for that purpose I am copying the simplest PCB I could found, a 4000W Dimmer:

[image]
[image]

The Squematic is this:

[image]

It has the next components:

- 1 TRIAC BTA416008 (STMicroelectronics, Series BTA41)
- 1 Capacitor 0.15 uF (Metallized Polypropylene Film, Grid  15.0 mm)
- 1 Capacitor 0.1 uF (630V 104J, Metallized Polypropylene Film, Grid 10.2 mm)
- 1 Resistor 2W 100Ω (Grid 15.0 mm)
- 1 Resistor 4.7 KΩ (Grid 7.5 mm)
- 1 DB3 DIAC (STMicroelectronics, Grid 7.5 mm)
- 1 Screw Terminal of Two Terminals (Grid: 8.0 mm)
- 1 Potentiometer 2W 500 KΩ (WTH118)

I am using EAGLE 9.1.3, to do the PCB Design the closest simmilar to the original I photocopied the PCB, and I obtained this:

[image]

and then I started to place the components on Eagle:

[image]

for some components I didn't have so much trouble, for example capacitors and resistors, but there are other ones that I don't know what should I do:

1. I am unable to find the BTA416008 TRIAC on Eagle Libraries, so I have to pick up another one, but I don't know if that is something correct to do.
2. I found a library for the DB3 DIAC on SnapEDA, but the grid does not correspond with the PCB Board and I don't know how to fix that.
3. There is no screw terminal with a grid of 8mm on Eagle Libraries, and I am unable to find a replacement
4. I am unable to find the potentiometer 2W 500 KΩ (WTH118) neither on Eagle Libraries or in SnapEDA

I am new on PCB Design, so I don't know how to fix that. Could you give me some recommendations?

Edit:
Electronic shops sell this circuit as a 4000W dimmer:

[image]

Comment: Not sure you can get 4000 watts out of this. More like 40 watts based on size of heatsink.

Comment: Well, I don't know if it is possible or not, but electronic shops sell this circuit as a "4000w Dimmer" (See my edit)

Comment: Pretty much anyone making a real board ends up making some of their own components in a custom library, either because things aren't there or because what is there is too absurd to be usable.  That said this is a bad choice of starting point - please, please do something that isn't mains powered!

Comment: A 4kW 230V triac dimmer will roughly dissipate ~17W. Anyway, for the PCB layout you need to create your own footprints (and symbols too).

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Why will roughly dissipate ~17W? How do I create my own footprints?

Comment: @ChrisStratton I am trying to use this circuit to test a CNC machine that I have that is going to mill a PCB Board, I think this is one of the simplest PCB Board designs I have seen, once I have the PCB milled, that's anoter history. I am not questioning about the danger of the circuit, I am questioning about the design of the PCB!

Comment: after testing that my CNC machine is working, and beeing comfortable with designing PCBs, I promise I will do something that isn't mains powered. I am just choosing that design because is the most simple one I could find, besides, if I don't study how these mains powered circuits work, when AM I GOING TO LEARN? I promise I am beeing very careful with all I do. I don't test anything if I am not comfortable with it

Comment: The maximum current through the triac is 4000W/230V ~= 17A. Most triacs dissipated about 1W/A at full conduction angle- check the datasheet to get a more accurate number for that particular part. How to create footprints? Learn to use the software. Refer to tutorials, videos, help files and practice. I don't use Eagle and even if I did this is not the appropriate place for a tutorial on a basic function of any EDA software. Note that a mains-powered PCB is not the best target for CNC milling if you're using something like Flatcam/engraver bit because of minimum creepage rules.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany my cnc machine is: Genmitsu CNC-3018 Pro .. and I wanted to use FlatCAM, if a mains-powered PCB is not the best target for CNC milling then, How do Dimmers that sell on Internet are made?

Comment: When you cut the board with an engraving bit it will only cut a narrow channel leaving most of the copper, outlining the traces, not what you are drawing on the computer. The gap is unacceptably small for mains operation.  https://i.imgur.com/ZVZHK9R.png Commercial boards use etching to leave large areas bereft of copper for proper insulation.